# trigger click on button ending with id's ending with number

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a requirement where I print all the email addresses in `<input type="text" value="emailaddress">` on the jsp page. I should be able to edit the field, so I have a button at the end of it. But the email addresses can be of any number. How to select the button ending with any number

```
$('#button_1').on("click", function() {

    //enter code here

});

 $('#button_2').on("click", function() {

        //enter code here

    });
```

I am trying to do something like

```
$('#button_'[]).on("click", function() {

});
```

Can someone help me with this solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS wildcard:

```
$("button[id^='button_']").click(function() {
    // button elements with id starting with "button_"
    // return($(this).attr('id'));
});

$("button[id*='button_']").click(function() {
    // button elements with id containing "button_"
    // return($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: How to know the button I have clicked on

Comment: `return $(this).attr('id')`

Comment: there exists an 'attribute starting with selector' -> `button[id^="button_"]` you should use **that** instead :)

Answer (score 1):

Also instead of giving an Id you can put a class on these buttons since class can be duplicated:

```
<button class='email' id="#button_1"/>
<button class='email' id="#button_2"/>
```

Then its easier to select only these:

```
$('.email').on("click", function() {
       // get access to the current button via this: 
       $(this).attr("value","delete"); 
});
```

Comment: I have to change the name of the button to `delete` or add.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [starts-with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) attribute selector.

You can do the following:

```
$('[id^="button_"]').on('click', function () {
  // your code here
});
```

The `$('[id^="button_"]')` selects all the elements that have an id beginning with `button_`. Then you are able to bind a single handler to cater for all button events.

Comment: can I be able to detect the button I have clicked on, is it the first button, 2nd button ?

Comment: `$(this).attr('id').split('button_')[1]`